# Reading and writing integer array to parcel

Tags: android, parcelable

I could not find any solution for how to treat with integer array in case of parcel (I want to use these two functions **dest.writeIntArray(storeId);**  and   **in.readIntArray(storeId);**).

Here is my code

```
public class ResponseWholeAppData implements Parcelable {
    private int storeId[];

    public int[] getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(int[] storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public ResponseWholeAppData(){
        storeId = new int[2];
        storeId[0] = 5;
        storeId[1] = 10;
    }

    public ResponseWholeAppData(Parcel in) {

        if(in.readByte() == (byte)1) 
             in.readIntArray(storeId);  //how to do this storeId=in.readIntArray();  ?                          
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        if(storeId!=null&&storeId.length>0)                   
        {
            dest.writeByte((byte)1);
            dest.writeIntArray(storeId);
        }
        else
            dest.writeByte((byte)0);

    }
    public static Parcelable.Creator<ResponseWholeAppData> getCreator() {
        return CREATOR;
    }

    public static void setCreator(Parcelable.Creator<ResponseWholeAppData> creator) {
        CREATOR = creator;
    }

    public static Parcelable.Creator<ResponseWholeAppData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ResponseWholeAppData>()
            {
        public ResponseWholeAppData createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new ResponseWholeAppData(in);
        }
        public ResponseWholeAppData[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new ResponseWholeAppData[size];
        }
            };      
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

When I use "`in.readIntArray(storeID)`", I get an error:

*"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.Parcel.readIntArray(Parcel.java:672)"*.

Instead of using "`readIntArray`" I used the following:

```
storeID = in.createIntArray();
```

Now there are no errors.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and then let you know.

Comment: Thanks. Had the same problem with readFloatArray(...) and createFloatArray() solved it.

Comment: 6 years later and still applicable. I couldn't understand for the life of me why readIntArray() threw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

I assume class MyObj implements Parcelable and implements all the required methods; I will suggest here only the details about reading / writing parcel.

If array size is known beforehand:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
    out.writeIntArray(mMyIntArray);        // In this example array length is 4
}

protected MyObj(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    mMyIntArray = new int[4];
    in.readIntArray(mMyIntArray);
}
```

Otherwise:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
    out.writeInt(mMyArray.length);        // First write array length
    out.writeIntArray(mMyIntArray);       // Then array content
}

protected MyObj(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    mMyIntArray = new int[in.readInt()];
    in.readIntArray(mMyIntArray);
}
```

Comment: Will cause a Crash on Samsung devices use above answer