# How to use a class field array in a Android Parcelable

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, parcelable

I created my own Parcelable class based on a [snippet](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/takecare/Android%3a%20Parcelable%20Class) to send custom data via an Intent. Using it, Android (Min. API 10) gives me an exception, what it wrong with that piece of code below? I broke it down to a minimum. Here it is:

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
private float[] data = null;

public MyParcelable(float[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
    /* After this line the exception is thrown */
    in.readFloatArray(data);
}

public static final Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Creator<MyParcelable>() {
    public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyParcelable(in);
    }

    public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyParcelable[size];
    }
};

public int describeContents() {
    return this.hashCode();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeFloatArray(data);
}

public float[] getData() {
    return data;
}
}
```

Comment: describeContents() returns bit mask, not hashCode!

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a solution quite a while I stumbled upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121543/reading-and-writing-integer-array-to-parcel) where LionKing gave a working hint.

The Parcelable class now looks like this:

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
private float[] data = null;

public MyParcelable(float[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
    /* The exception is gone */
    data = in.createFloatArray();
}

public static final Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Creator<MyParcelable>() {
    public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyParcelable(in);
    }

    public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyParcelable[size];
    }
};

public int describeContents() {
    return this.hashCode();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeFloatArray(data);
}

public float[] getData() {
    return data;
}
}
```

This solution works also with the other base type arrays.